# I'm learning Python and I don't understand this notation

Tags: python, python-3.6

Note how the start is always included, and the end always excluded. This makes sure that `s[:i] + s[i:]` is always equal to `s`:

```
>>> word[:2] + word[2:]
'Python'
>>> word[:4] + word[4:]
'Python'
```

I don't understand what thee above notation is.

Comment: Please edit your post, and put the relevant code in the correct form.

Comment: The word for it is `slice` notation.

Answer (score 4):

The python indices are as below

```
P   y   t   h   o   n
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

So if you ask `s[0:1]` it is start index of `0` to end index of `1`. Thus only `P`
So if you ask `s[4:]`, anything right of index at 4(start).
So if you ask `s[:4]`, anything left of index at 4(end).

Comment: add a space at the numbers level and delete the 6 :)

Answer (score 1):

If the word is `Python`

This means each letters index will be as follows and you can select each letter by this method

```
P = word[0]
y = word[1]
t = word[2]
h = word[3]
o = word[4]
n = word[5]
```

You can also select a range or letter by using `slice notation`.  This uses the `:` in between the desired range

So...

```
word[2:4]
```

This will select the letters in index `[2]` and `[3]` but will NOT include the last index number `[4]`

If you leave it blank `word[:]` you will return the whole string `Python` because it will include everything from the `start` to the `end`.

If you use `word[:2]`  it will return `Pyt`

If you use `word[2:]` it wil return `thon`
 note that the last letter is included when the right side is left blank.